# Angularjs Data Binding Not Updating in Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

there is a problem that I couldn't understand. 
I copied my code below. 
The problem is when I clicked on a number it must update $scope.screen.operation but it is not updating it. Do I know data binding in a wrong way ?

```js
(function() {
    var app = angular.module('electronApp', []);

    app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {

        $scope.numbers = {
            one: '',
            two: ''
        };

        $scope.operation = '';

        $scope.screen = {
            operation: $scope.numbers.one +' '+ $scope.operation +' '+ $scope.numbers.two,
            result: ''
        };

        $scope.number = function (number) {

            if($scope.operation == '') {
                $scope.numbers.one = '' + $scope.numbers.one + number;
            }

            console.log($scope.screen.operation);

        }

    });
})();
```

```css
.screen{
    border: 1px solid #bbb;
    background-color: #fafafa;
    border-radius: 2px;
    height: 200px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    padding: 15px;
    position: relative;
}
.screen .operation-list{
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.screen .result{
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: absolute;
    right: 15px;
    bottom: 15px;
    left: 15px;
    text-align: right;
}

.button-box{
    margin-top: 5px;
}
.button-box .row div{
    padding: 5px 5px;
}
.button-box .row div:first-child{
    padding-left: 0;
}
.button-box .row div:last-child{
    padding-right: 0;
}
.button-box .row div button{
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="electronApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello World!</title>
 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  
 <div class="container-fluid" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
      <div class="screen col-xs-12">
          <div class="operation-list" ng-bind="screen.operation"></div>
          <div class="result">
              <span>{{screen.result}}</span>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 button-box">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-3"><button class="btn btn-default" button-type="number" ng-click="number(1)">1</button></div>
              <div class="col-xs-3"><button class="btn btn-default" button-type="number" ng-click="number(2)">2</button></div>
              <div class="col-xs-3"><button class="btn btn-default" button-type="number" ng-click="number(3)">3</button></div>
              <div class="col-xs-3"><button class="btn btn-default" button-type="operation">+</button></div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-3"><button class="btn btn-default" button-type="number" ng-click="number(4)">4</button></div>
              <div class="col-xs-3"><button class="btn btn-default" button-type="number" ng-click="number(5)">5</button></div>
              <div class="col-xs-3"><button class="btn btn-default" button-type="number" ng-click="number(6)">6</button></div>
              <div class="col-xs-3"><button class="btn btn-default" button-type="operation">-</button></div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-3"><button class="btn btn-default" button-type="number" ng-click="number(7)">7</button></div>
              <div class="col-xs-3"><button class="btn btn-default" button-type="number" ng-click="number(8)">8</button></div>
              <div class="col-xs-3"><button class="btn btn-default" button-type="number" ng-click="number(9)">9</button></div>
              <div class="col-xs-3"><button class="btn btn-default" button-type="operation">*</button></div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-3"><button class="btn btn-default" button-type="number" ng-click="number(0)">0</button></div>
              <div class="col-xs-3"><button class="btn btn-default" button-type="clear">Tmzl</button></div>
              <div class="col-xs-3"><button class="btn btn-default" button-type="backspace">Sil</button></div>
              <div class="col-xs-3"><button class="btn btn-default" button-type="operation">/</button></div>
          </div>
      </div>
 </div>
 
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

$scope.screen.operation becomes a string which is not data bound.

Not entirely sure what we're trying to achieve but a possible solution could invole a function that returns the operation string you would want, and calling that:

```
$scope.makeOperation = function () {
  return $scope.numbers.one + ' ' + $scope.operation + ' ' + $scope.numbers.two;
}
```

...

```
$scope.number = function (number) {
  if ($scope.operation == '') {
     $scope.numbers.one = '' + $scope.numbers.one + number;
  }
  $scope.screen.operation = $scope.makeOperation();
  console.log($scope.screen.operation);
}
```

Comment: You are correct, but perhaps you could offer a suggested solution instead of just pointing out the error?

Comment: Added a possible solution. Hasn't been tested but something like that.

Comment: Thanks for answer, you wrote a good solution and I got the point of my problem from answer of @Quiriacus.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you expect `$scope.screen.operation` in

```
$scope.screen = {
    operation: $scope.numbers.one +' '+ $scope.operation +' '+ $scope.numbers.two,
    result: ''
};
```

to be automatically re-evaluated because a term on the right hand side of the assignment is updated.

AngularJS data binding does not work like that. `$scope.screen.operation` will get evaluated **once** (when the controller is initialized) based on the value the terms on the right hand side had at the time.

Then it's up to you to explicitly update `$scope.screen.operation` through the UI (two-way data binding) or through the controller's logic for example.

You can either explicitly update the `$scope.screen.operation` in your `$scope.number` function

or

Use `$watch` to detect changes on `$scope.numbers.one` (that change takes place in your `$scope.number` function at the moment.)

```
$scope.$watch('numbers.one', function(newVal, oldVal) {
    $scope.screen.operation = newVal + ' ' + $scope.operation + ' ' + $scope.numbers.two;
}
```

You'll probably want to do the same for `$scope.numbers.two`.

Comment: Thanks for awnser, I got it the logic data binding in angular code side now thanks to you.